# I cannot get pygame to work with python

Tags: python, windows, installation, pygame, 64-bit

I have had a few dozen attempts at installing pygame to my python. I have tried many different versions of the programs.

I am running a 64 bit version of windows 10, and seem to be required to use an unofficial .whl file to get pygame, however i do not know how to use this file.

I have tried running several variants of commands that was explained in many areas, however they all ether return errors, or yield no success.

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Details. What errors are you getting for what methods are you trying.

Comment: Welcome tpo stack ovrflow ! "Am i doing something wrong?" Yes, you should take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) before posting

Comment: Have you tried `pip install C:\Users\Shaun\Downloads\nameofthefile.whl`?

Answer (score 0):

I too had problems while following the instructions on the website.

I did it the traditional way, Using PIP.

Just open cmd. Upgrade your pip.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

and then

```
pip install pygame
```

This will automaticallly get the correct version of pygame .whl package according to your system configurtaion. Make sure you remember this version of .whl package as it is the one you will be looking for in future installation of .whl packages.